# MySQL total expenses of employees in a timeframe

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, sum

So I need to make a procedure that sums all the expenses from the salaries of employees in a given timeframe. However, some employees might not have been hired from the start of the time frame.

Here is what my Worker table columns are:

```
Name| Last_Name | email| Date_of_Recruitment | Salary | Newspaper_Name |Password |initial_salary
```

I want the expenses from January to July and an employee was hired in March, I want his salary to be counted for for March, April, May, June, July only.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's difficult to answer your question without more details. Please [edit] it to show a few rows of sample data and the sample result you want. If possible please include some edge cases (like a person hired on the last day of February) in your sample. **Pro tip** creating these sorts of samples is a really good way to make sure you work out your requirements before starting to write queries.

Comment: This is not how Stack works. Check some documentation about https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 and ask is you have any doubt

Comment: @marcdecline This question is about MySql, not the Microsoft product.

Comment: ok sorry @O.Jones, Better https://www.google.com/search?q=procedures+in+mysql&rlz=1C1WPZC_enES916ES916&oq=procedures+in+mysql&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.5383j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 ? If you're willing to do a student's homework, that's your problem, I've done too much I think doing a google search. Have a good day

Comment: I only mention it because I remember when I was a n00b and very confused about SQL dialects, and I hope to spare others the same confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your table has just one record per employee, I *think* you want `timestampdiff()`:

```
select sum(salary 
    * timestampdiff(month, greatest('2020-01-01', date_of_recruitment), '2020-07-01')
) total_salaries
from mytable
where date_of_recruitment <= '2020-07-01'
```

For employees that were hired before July 2020, the logic is to count the elapsed month between the recruitment date and July, and multiply that by the salary. You can then `sum()` the results over the entire dataset.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot!